# How to make a select input that is dependent on other inputs to always show a default value in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, select, use-state

I have two radio buttons: `radio1` and `radio2`, and one `select` input.
The Select values depend on the radio buttons.
I want to set the `select` value to `1` whenever I select `radio1`.
I've tried setting `defaultValue` and `value` to the `select` input but every time I switch back to `radio1` from `radio2`, the value is always set to `2`.

Here's my code, any help is truly appreciated:

```
import "./styles.css";
import { useState } from "react";

const selectItems = {
  name: "size",
  fields: {
    radio1: [
      {
        value: "1"
      },
      {
        value: "2"
      }
    ],
    radio2: [
      {
        value: "2"
      },
      {
        value: "3"
      },
      {
        value: "4"
      }
    ]
  }
};

const App = () => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({ radio: "radio1", select: "2" });
  const handleChange = (name, value) => {
    setValues((s) => {
      return { ...s, [name]: value };
    });
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>
        How do I make the Select always be '1' when Radio1 is selected after
        selecting Radio2?
      </h2>
      <input
        type="radio"
        id="radio1"
        value="radio1"
        name="radio"
        onChange={() => handleChange("radio", "radio1")}
      />
      <label htmlFor="radio1">Radio1</label>
      <input
        type="radio"
        id="radio2"
        value="radio2"
        name="radio"
        onChange={() => handleChange("radio", "radio2")}
      />
      <label htmlFor="radio2">Radio2</label>
      <br />
      <select
        id="size"
        name="size"
        onChange={(e) => handleChange("select", e.target.value)}
      >
        {selectItems.fields[values.radio].map(({ value }) => {
          return (
            <option key={value} value={value}>
              {value}
            </option>
          );
        })}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

example: https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-danny-p1l3s?file=/src/App.js:0-1460

Edit:

As suggested by some answers, I have tried setting 'selected' as true. In fact, I have tried this before and forgot to mention it on my question. This seem to work, it gives me the desired effect on the browser, but then I get this error on the console:

```
Warning: Use the `defaultValue` or `value` props on <select> instead of setting `selected` on <option>.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem here is `<option>` is taking the same `key` value. When you are selecting radio2, key becomes 2.Then you are selecting radio1 and for that `<select>` has `<option>` with `key=2`. That is why `<select>` value not changing. The proof is if you change all `<option>` values unique, example for radio1 {1, 2} and for radio2 {3, 4, 5} your code works fine.

There may be multiple workarounds but the proper way to solve this is having unique `id` for each of the `<option>`.

```
const selectItems = {
  name: "size",
  fields: {
    radio1: [
      {
        value: "1",
        id: 1
      },
      {
        value: "2",
        id: 2
      }
    ],
    radio2: [
      {
        value: "2",
        id: 3
      },
      {
        value: "3",
        id: 4
      },
      {
        value: "4",
        id: 5
      }
    ]
  }
};
------------------------------------------
<select
        id="size"
        name="size"
        onChange={(e) => handleChange("select", e.target.value)}
      >
        {selectItems.fields[values.radio].map(({ value, id }) => {
          return (
            <option key={id} value={value}>
              {value}
            </option>
          );
        })}
      </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Element `<option>` has property `selected` that is responsible for determining which item is currently selected.
That is the property that will help you to decide which item should be currently selected at any given time.
To illustrate this, I have added the following check to your  element:
`<element selected={value === '1'}>` and now every time you change the radio from `radio1` to `radio2` the value changes to 1 as you asked in your question.

My response here is more of a guidance, do not treat as exact step by step instruction as I did not think of any other ways that your program might work or handle different behaviours.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @oleg-gulevskyy - I've tried setting 'selected' on option, but end up getting an error. I've edited my question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a new state which is called `defaultValue`. As a result, with setting the value property of `select` tag by `defaultValue`, you can achieve your goal:

```
const App = () => {
  const [values, setValues] = useState({ radio: "radio1", select: "2" });
  const [defaultValue, setDefaultValue] = useState(0);
  const handleChange = (name, value) => {
    setValues((s) => {
      return { ...s, [name]: value };
    });
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setDefaultValue(selectItems.fields[values.radio][0].value);
  }, [values]);
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h2>
        How do I make the Select always be '1' when Radio1 is selected after
        selecting Radio2?
      </h2>
      <input
        type="radio"
        id="radio1"
        value="radio1"
        name="radio"
        onChange={() => handleChange("radio", "radio1")}
      />
      <label for="radio1">Radio1</label>
      <input
        type="radio"
        id="radio2"
        value="radio2"
        name="radio"
        onChange={() => handleChange("radio", "radio2")}
      />
      <label for="radio2">Radio2</label>
      <br />
      <select
        id="size"
        name="size"
        value={defaultValue}
        onChange={(e) => handleChange("select", e.target.value)}
      >
        {selectItems.fields[values.radio].map(({ value }, index) => {
          return (
            <option key={value} value={value}>
              {value}
            </option>
          );
        })}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

[image: Edit laughing-engelbart-ok8jy]

Comment: Thanks for the answer @majid-m - I've tried setting 'selected' on option, but end up getting an error. I've edited my question to reflect this.

Comment: @AndreVitorio Updated answer! Please see it again.